# Run process as Daemon on AWS Infrastructure

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-ecs

I would like to run a process as daemon on AWS Infrastructure that is responsible to read the AWS SQS Queue and make some process.

My first approach is to use a docker container deployed on ECS Container service. So I will be on `while true loop`, sleeping for some seconds. Using this, I can control the sleep time between processing, so If my SQS queue is full, I could decrease the sleep time. So

I know that is possible to use AWS Lambda scheduled as a cron job, but I have no control over the cron time (decrease or increase in response of sqs size).

The AWS Lambda approach is simpler and there is no need of "any" infrastructure, but it less flexible. 
Does anyone know another approach?

Comment: You could use the Lambda scheduler thing and inside your lambda handler you could just ask SQS for 20 messages (I believe that is the max you can get at a time). If it got all 20 messages then before it finishes it re-invokes itself using the aws-sdk (`AWS.Lambda.invoke(context.functionName)`). If there were less than 20 messages then it would simply end successfully after processing those messages.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the way AWS Lambda handles cron scheduling under the hood (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) you should be able to find the Cloudwatch event that is triggering your lambda and modify it from within the lambda itself. Documentation for the programmatic APIs for Lambda and Cloudwatch Events is fairly scarce, though, so you'll have to figure a lot out for yourself.

All in all, doesn't really sound like an easier approach than just running your own container, although if you have a lot of these sorts of things to do it might not hurt to package it all in a library.